# Golang showing different capacities when slicing something differently

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I'm trying to understand slices in Go, and have came across the following code ( [Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/-4sJPYS--SY) ):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    example1(s)
    fmt.Printf("\n")
    example2(s)
}

func example1(s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("Example 1: \n")
    printSlice(s)

    s = s[:4]
    printSlice(s)
}

func example2(s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("Example 2: \n")
    printSlice(s)

    s = s[2:]
    printSlice(s)
}

func printSlice(s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
}
```

For which the output is:

```
Example 1: 
len=6 cap=6 [1 2 3 4 5 6]
len=4 cap=6 [1 2 3 4]

Example 2: 
len=6 cap=6 [1 2 3 4 5 6]
len=4 cap=4 [3 4 5 6]
```

While the length of the slices looks alright, what I don't undertand is why the capacity after slicing is `6` in the first example and `4` in the second example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The capacity of the slice is the number of elements that can be stored in the underlying array starting at the beginning of the slice. Your underlying array can store 6 elements. In `example1`, you create a new slice starting at the first element and extending for 4 elements, but the capacity is still 6 because your slice starts at the beginning of the underlying array. In `example2`, the slice starts at element 2 of the underlying array, so there's only room for 4 more elements, so the capacity is 4.

[This article](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro) gives a good explanation of how slices work.